# get file name for url php

Tags: php, html, url

I wanted to know how to get the current file name in PHP to be able to load the same file in a different directory.

```
index.php
works.php

lang/de/
   index.php
   works.php
lang/pl/
   index.php
   works.php

<div id="language">
    <a href="../../index.php" class="lang">EN</a>
    <a class="lang" href="index.php">DE</a>
    <a class="lang" href="../pl/index.php">PL</a>
</div>
```

The current method is redirecting the lang URL, allways to index.php.
I would love to know how to redirect from works.php to lang/de/works.php without redirecting to lang/de/index.php

Sorry if i'm getting you confused

Comment: You should really google this stuff.

`<?php basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>`

Comment: Hi! Sorry, i edited the post with a lot of information now... could u cheack it now, plz

Comment: Be careful with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], anyone can inject other data in this value. It is vulnerable to XSS. You have to filter it to prevent those attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<?php

$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>

<div id="language">
    <a href="../../<?php echo $page;?>" class="lang">EN</a>
    <a class="lang" href="<?php echo $page;?>">DE</a>
    <a class="lang" href="../pl/<?php echo $page;?>">PL</a>
</div>
```

You would save the current file name in the $page variable.  Then echo it out and replace index.php in your links.

Answer (score 1):

You should really google this stuff.

```
<?php basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>
```

[GOOGLE](https://www.google.com/search?q=get%20current%20filename%20php&oq=get%20current%20file%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.5661j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Now that you added some code, here ya go.

```
<div id="language">
    <a href="../../<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" class="lang">EN</a>
    <a class="lang" href="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">DE</a>
    <a class="lang" href="../pl/<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">PL</a>
</div>
```

FYI, `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` get's the name of the current file and returns just that. In other words, it will return "index.php" or "works.php"

Comment: You can also set it in a variable like what user2620860 said.